# Stop Vim from yanking visual selected text

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

Let's say I have a file like this

```
(abc)
(123)
(456)
```

I want to yank `abc` and paste it in place of `123` and `456`.
I would `yi)` on the first line. Then go down a line and paste it with `vi)p`.
But for the `456`, vim will paste the last visual selected text which is `123` instead of `abc`. The file is now looks like this:

```
(abc)
(abc)
(123)
```

This can be solve by specify a register before the yank/paste operation but I usually forget to include it. Is there anyway I can prevent vim visual select from yanking selected text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the second paste is determined by the first paste that substitute de default register with what has been overridden.

The standard solution for that is to include the following mapping in your `.vimrc` file:

`xnoremap p pgvy`

When you paste in visual mode (`x`):

- It select what has been previously selected (`gv`) and
- Yank it (`y`)

Comment: A solution has been posted in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163947/paste-multiple-times)

Answer (score 4):

Since patch [8.2.4242](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fb55207ed17918c8a2a6cadf5ad9d5fcf686a7ab) you can use `P` in place of `p` in visual mode to put without yanking- i.e., use `vi)P` in your example to get the desired behavior.

---

To go slightly further, I have created a plugin [visput](https://github.com/andymass/vim-visput) which enables this behavior for both `p` and `P` and also enables `.` repeat to work after visual operations.